# How to find biggest value for two hashmap based on keys

Tags: java, hashmap

Suppose I have two Hashmaps. How can I find the biggest value from the two Hashmaps with respect to each key.
The values has to be compared based on the keys only.
Example: first it has to take common keys from two hash maps, and then it has to find biggest value's for each key.
I want value to be printed when map1(value)>map2(value)

**Map1**

```
------------------
S.NO      Amount
1   68000
2   197500
3   6468000
------------------
```

**Map2**

```
------------------
S.NO      Amount
1   500000
2   500000
3   300000
4   500000
9   999999999999
10  5000
11  10000
--------------------
```

Comment: what if the key exists only in one map? ignore it?

Comment: I'd suggest a for loop over the key set in one, and to look at values in the other & do your comparison logic.

Comment: What did you try?  What are you having trouble with?  What you are talking about is about 4 lines of code, sounds simple enough.

Comment: I want biggest value not keys. based on the keys i want biggeat value(Amount).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (looping through all entries in map 1 and checking to see if they are contained in map 2, if so then compare).  I'm assuming that your HashMaps are of Integers:

```
while (Integer key : Map1.keySet()) {
  if (Map2.contains(key)) {
    int a = Map1.get(key);
    int b = Map2.get(key);
    if (a > b) {
      System.out.println(a);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to get biggest values not keys

Comment: Those are the biggest values.  Map1.get(key) will return the value assigned to the key of "key."  Likewise, Map2.get(key) will get the value assigned to the key of "key" but in Map2.  I then compare these two values.

Comment: Can u please write full code... I'm trying the above code but not able to do it. plese give me full code with example